# Need help analysing warning from Unity app on Android

Tags: android, linux, unity-game-engine, android-permissions, logcat

I have a Unity app which I'm deploying to my Android device. When viewing the Android logs with [Logcat](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html) I keep seeing the following warning (a few times per second)

```
2024/03/07 08:32:04.996 30340 30340 Warn UnityMain type=1400 audit(0.0:324427): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  name="/" dev="dmabuf" ino=1 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_32:s0:c166,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=0 app=com.Fisheye.ARTutorial3
```

I'm very new to all of this so I need some guidance as to what could be causing this warning and how to get rid of it. Or should I not bother?